# Data DatePicker - Processamento

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Senhores:

A data que eu tenho no datepicker é no formato `dd/mm/yy`, porém, a data no banco de dados é `yy-mm-dd` (campo date). Como eu faço para que no datepicker apresente a data padrão BR e quando vier via POST, entrar como formato EN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se quiser tratar no **envio**:

```
var dataQuebrada = $("#datepicker").val().split("/");
var novaData = new Date("20" + dataQuebrada[2], dataQuebrada[1] - 1, dataQuebrada[0]); 
// new Date(year, month, day);
// -1 no mês porque ele começa do 0
// "20", pois você só tem os 2 últimos digitos
```

Se quiser tratar no **recebimento**:

```
var $datepicker = $("#datepicker");
var dataQuebrada = $("#datepicker").val().split("-");
var novaData = new Date("20" + dataQuebrada[0], dataQuebrada[1] - 1, dataQuebrada[2]); 
$datepicker.datepicker();
$datepicker.datepicker('setDate', novaData);
```

Comment: Não entendi... O Post vem no php.

Comment: @AndréBaill Atualizei a resposta

Answer (score 1):

Eu costumo tratar esses dados no lado do servidor, e usando PHP faço assim:

```
<input type="text" name="minha_data" 
 id="minha_data" class="form-control data datepicker" 
 value="<?php data_us_to_br($geral->dt_atendimento); ?>"    
 placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" maxlength="10" minlength="10" />
```

e no lado do servidor, quando vou receber o POST assim:

```
$valorMinhaData = data_br_to_us($_POST['dt_verificacao']);
```

e as funções que estou usando no caso são essas :

```
function data_us_to_br($dateUSA)
{
    if($dateUSA) {
         $ano = substr($dateUSA, 0, 4);
         $mes = substr($dateUSA, 5, 2);
         $dia = substr($dateUSA, 8, 2);
         $dateBR = $dia .'/'. $mes .'/'. $ano;

         return $dateBR;
    } 

    return NULL;
}


function data_br_to_us($dateBR)
{
    if($dateBR) {
         $ano = substr($dateBR, 6, 4);
         $mes = substr($dateBR, 3, 2);
         $dia = substr($dateBR, 0, 2);
         $dateUSA = $ano .'-'. $mes .'-'. $dia;

         return $dateUSA;
    } 

    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Da p/ fazer assim com uma única linha de comando:

```
var d = $.datepicker.formatDate( "yy-mm-dd", $('#calendario').datepicker('getDate') );
```

Onde a variável **d** fica no formato mysql

E o **$('#calendario').datepicker('getDate')** Pega no formato que estiver

> https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Mas e como eu recupero ela no php? Grato

Comment: nesse caso você pode usar o javascript para preencher algum campo do seu formulario e enviar pelo submit, ou fazer um ajax, tanto faz